# Optimum way to get translation to support localization for a mobile app being developed

Tags: android, localization, translation, multilingual, language-translation

I need to add localization support for an android mobile app which is under development but very near to last milestone. To add proper localization support we need translations of required **text/strings** in different languages. For instance, Facebook supports around 43 languages right now.

Big companies have employees on different countries or they hire third party small companies to get translations. Another way to get translations is to engage volunteers. First one is not suited for a startup or individual developer because its required certain amount of money. Second one is possible after releasing initial binary into market and have to wait to get volunteers until app get popularity.

**Is there any other way which costs as low as possible ?**

Answer (score 0):

The only truly free crowdsourced site I have found is [Ackuna](https://ackuna.com/). Post your project and if its not too big and you are lucky you'll get translations into few languages. Then you can help other developers to translate their projects into your native language and get them to help with translation on your project.